# How to get the values from the loop to the blade - laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, laravel-blade

I used for loop to fetch a query and able to store in a array. The array for eg: looks like when i:

> dd($s);

```
  array:2 [▼
  "Block A" => array:49 [▶]
  "Block K" => array:149 [▶]
]
```

Now with these each arrays, I have more data and I want to display it on the select box in the blade.

```
array:2 [▼
"Block A" => array:49 [▼
0 => array:1 [▼
  "Block A0" => "1"
]
```

I want to to display **1** only which is at the **Block A0 => 1**

> homeController.php

```
foreach ($v as $f ) {
    $m[$i] = [
            $l.$i => $f->rNum,
          ];

    $s[$l] = $m;
    $i++;
  }
 $s = (array_filter($s));

 return view('home')->with($s);
 // I have also tried with

 //return view('home')->with('res',$s);
```

> Home.blade.php

```
@foreach ($res as $s)
    <option value="> {{_____?____}}" </option>
             //I only want to display 1  to 49 here
@endforeach
```

**Remember there are 2 arrays, Block A and Block K**

so the select box should have all the values of Block A (i.e.: 1 to 49 )and all the values of Block K (i.e.: 1 to 149 ) in the second select box.

I am not too sure how the get the value in here, but at least i am able to get the values in the controller

[image]

**

> COMPLETE CONTROLLER CODE

```
public function viewHall($id){

  $path = request()->path();

  $substring = substr($path, 0,10);

  $title;
  $viewApp;

  $viewroom = "";
  $s[] = array();

  $i = 1;
  if ($substring == "view/hall/"){
    $viewApp = DB::select('Select * from applications where hall = "'.$id .'" AND status = "pending"');

     foreach ($viewApp as $k) {
       $a[] = $k->flat;
}

        $countA = (count($a));

        foreach ($a as $l) {

                    $viewroom = DB::select('Select applications.*  , residences.*  , rooms.* from applications
                    LEFT Join residences on applications.resi = residences.resiName
                    LEFT JOIN rooms on rooms.resiID = residences.id
                    where hall = "'.$id .'" AND status =  "pending" AND rooms.available = 0
                    AND rooms.flatName ="'.$l.'" group by  rooms.flatName, rooms.roomNum');


                         foreach ($viewroom as $f ) {
                           $s[$l][$i] = [
                                      $l => $f->roomNum,
                                  ];

                                  $i++;


                         }


                  }

                  $s = (array_filter($s));





    $title = "Hall (" . $id .")";

    return view('admin.viewapp')->with('applications', $viewApp)->with('title',$title)->with('rid',$id)->with('rooms',$viewroom)
                                ->with('roomNs', $s)->with('flat',$a)->with('flatc', $m);
  }

  elseif ($substring == "view/resi/"){
    $viewApp = DB::select('Select * from applications where resi = "'.$id .'" AND status = "pending"');

    $viewroom = DB::select('Select applications.*  , residences.*  , rooms.* from applications
                           LEFT Join residences on applications.resi = residences.resiName
                           LEFT JOIN rooms on rooms.resiID = residences.id
                           where resi = "'.$id .'" AND status =  "pending" AND rooms.available = 0');
    $title = "Residence (" . $id .")";
  }
  elseif ($substring == "view/year/"){
    $viewApp = DB::select('Select * from applications where year = "'.$id .'" AND status = "pending"');

    $viewroom = DB::select('Select applications.*  , residences.*  , rooms.* from applications
                           LEFT Join residences on applications.resi = residences.resiName
                           LEFT JOIN rooms on rooms.resiID = residences.id
                           where applications.year = "'.$id .'" AND status =  "pending" AND rooms.available = 0');
    $title = "Year (" . $id .")";
  }
  else{
    $viewApp = DB::select('Select * from applications where status = "pending"');

    $viewroom = DB::select('Select applications.*  , residences.*  , rooms.* from applications
                           LEFT Join residences on applications.resi = residences.resiName
                           LEFT JOIN rooms on rooms.resiID = residences.id
                           where  status =  "pending" AND rooms.available = 0');
    $title = "View All";
  }

  return view('admin.viewapp')->with('applications', $viewApp)->with('title',$title)->with('rid',$id)->with('rooms',$viewroom)
                              -with('roomNs', $roomN);

}
```

**

**

> View.blade.php

```
<form class="" action="{{URL('process/')}}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <table class="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">#</th>
              <th scope="col">Hall</th>
              <th scope="col">Residence</th>
              <th scope="col">Year</th>
              <th scope="col">Flat</th>
              <th scope="col">Room</th>
              <th scope="col">Status</th>
              <th scope="col">Submitted on</th>
              <th scope="col">Approve</th>
              <th scope="col">Reject</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>

              @foreach ($applications as $show)
              <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$show->id}}">
              <input type="hidden" name="hall" value="{{$show->hall}}">
              <input type="hidden" name="resID" value="{{$show->resID}}">
              <input type="hidden" name="year" value="{{$show->year}}">
              <input type="hidden" name="flat" value="{{$show->flat}}">
              <th scope="row">{{$i}}</th>
              <td>{{$show->hall}}</td>
              <td>{{$show->resi}}</td>
              <td>{{$show->year}}</td>
              <td>{{$show->flat}}</td>
              <td>


                <div class="form-group">
                   <select class="form-control" id="roomNo" name="roomNo" required autofocus>
                     <option value="" selected>Select Room Number</option>
                     <?php $i=0; ?>
                     @foreach ($roomNs as $key1 => $value1)
                             @foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
                                 @foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3)
                                     <option value="{{ $value3 }}"> {{ $value3 }} </option>
                                 @endforeach
                             @endforeach
                          @endforeach
                   </select>
                 </div>



              </td>
              <td>{{$show->status}}</td>
              <td>{{$show->created_at}}</td>
              <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"name="approve" value="Approve"></td>
              <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"name="reject" value="Reject"></td>
            </tr>

            @endforeach
          </tbody>
        </table>
        </form>
```

**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so since that's your array structure what you want to do is to use 3 foreach loops for that.

Assuming that in your controller returns this:

```
return view('home')->with('res', $s);
```

Here is what you want to do in your view:

```
@foreach ($res as $key1 => $value1)
    @foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
        @foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3)
            <option value="{{ $value3 }}"> {{ $key3 }}" </option>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

PS

Please name your variables properly. Don't name like `$s` or `$res`, it will help you a lot in the future as your project grows if you name your variables appropriately.

Follow up answer:

In your controller. I'm not sure what is the value of `$v` variable and what are you trying to do in the foreach loop. I think to fix your issue about getting 100 data for "Block K" instead of 149, you must do this:

```
foreach ($v as $f ) {
    $s[$l][$i] = [
        $l.$i => $f->rNum,
    ];

    $i++;
}
```

Answer #2:

This is what I recommend in your view:

```
<form class="" action="{{URL('process/')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Hall</th>
                <th scope="col">Residence</th>
                <th scope="col">Year</th>
                <th scope="col">Flat</th>
                <th scope="col">Room</th>
                <th scope="col">Status</th>
                <th scope="col">Submitted on</th>
                <th scope="col">Approve</th>
                <th scope="col">Reject</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ($applications as $show)
                <tr>
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$show->id}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="hall" value="{{$show->hall}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="resID" value="{{$show->resID}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="year" value="{{$show->year}}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="flat" value="{{$show->flat}}">
                    <th scope="row">{{$i}}</th>
                    <td>{{$show->hall}}</td>
                    <td>{{$show->resi}}</td>
                    <td>{{$show->year}}</td>
                    <td>{{$show->flat}}</td>
                    <td>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control" id="roomNo" name="roomNo" required autofocus>
                                <option value="" selected>Select Room Number</option>
                                <?php $i=0; ?>
                                @foreach ($roomNs[$show->flat] as $key1 => $value1)
                                    @foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2)
                                        <option value="{{ $value2 }}"> {{ $value2 }} </option>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
                        </div>



                    </td>
                    <td>{{$show->status}}</td>
                    <td>{{$show->created_at}}</td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"name="approve" value="Approve"></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"name="reject" value="Reject"></td>
                </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

> Blockquote

Comment: Thanks @aceraven , I tried this and its working fine. However, i just realised an issue. The array which show Block A has 49 and Block K has 149 arrays, is wrong. These are coming from database in a loop. and there are two sets of arrays. Block A and Block K. In block A, I have 49, which is correct and in block K , I have 100. So In the view, I am getting 49 in the first select box but in the second select box i am getting which is Block K, I am getting 149. How can I only get the 100 arrays in this option? Block K starts from the 50th array in the loop. Can you help please. Thanks.

Comment: i have attached the screenshot of the output.

Comment: thanks, i will try. The $v is the sql query I am fetching. I am trying to numbers inside this each Blocks. rNum are the numbers.

Comment: ok cool, i got the  required values from the controller using dd($s); However, the loops in the views are not still showing correct values in both the selectboxes (as seen in the screenshot). – Sarah Malik 10 mins ago

Comment: @SarahMalik, can you share us the whole code in the controller? So that I can further help you.

Comment: @SarahMalik, I don't see the `foreach ($v as $f ) {`. Where did you put this code?

Comment: sorry, I messed up wit my edit here. I have updated the code here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192248/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-aceraven777).

Comment: question, what is the difference between `$m` and `$s`?

Comment: well there is no difference. I was trying to work arnd the code and have really messed it up whch is creating bit of confusion